# How can I use a Chrome intent to open google maps app and start navigation?

Tags: google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to launch the google maps app with a Chrome intent just like web app of maps does it, this URI works but I don't know how I can pass the params correctly, I don't know what is **12z/data** for example

*intent://maps.app.goo.gl/?link=https://www.google.com.mx/maps/dir//Texcoco%2BCentro,%2BJard%25C3%25ADn%2BMunicipal%2BConstitucion,%2BCentro,%2BTexcoco,%2BEstado%2Bde%2BM%25C3%25A9xico/@19.5304781,-98.8971503,12z/data%3D!4m6!4m5!1m0!1m2!1m1!1s0x85d1e7a7a346c29d:0x9022698255f42430!3e0!11m1!6b1?entry%3Dml&apn=com.google.android.apps.maps&amv=914018424&isi=585027354&ibi=com.google.Maps&ius=comgooglemapsurl&utm_campaign=ml_promo&ct=ml-nav-nopromo-dr&mt=8&pt=9008&efr=1#Intent;package=com.google.android.gms;scheme=https;end;*